# How to install the custom app to the Android phone for using Sony-SmartEyeGlass?

Tags: sony, sony-smarteyeglass

Dear Developers of the Sony SmartEyeGlass(SED-E1)

This is the 1st time question to the Stack Overflow.And my English ability is poor.You may think that my question is a little hard to understand, please read them with patience.

About 1 week ago, I bought and got a new one of the Sony SmartEyeGlass. Today I would like to ask how to use our custom Android application on this glass.

Our custom Android app was developed only with the Android SDK. We have not used the Sony SmartEyeGlass SDK yet. Now this custom app is installed in the Android smart phone(Sony Experia SOL26) and it can work in a normal way on the phone.
 The other day, I got the Android app "SmartEyeglass" from the Google Play site.
The app "SmartEyeglass" can  work in a normal way on the phone(Experia SOL26), but the app(="SmartEyeglass") cannot show our custom app on its menu "application".

{My Question}
 If we want to work our custom app on the SmartEyeGlass(SED-E1), what should we do? Should we modify our custom app by using the Sony SmartEyeGlass SDK?

Please answer my question. I'm looking forward to your answer.

Best Regards, Hiroyasu Takeda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you will have to use the SmartEyeglass SDK to have your app appear on the glasses. I would recommend checking out our documentation on the SmartEyeglass developer site here:

https://developer.sony.com/develop/wearables/smarteyeglass-sdk/

Download the SDK and try running one of the code samples. This will give you a better idea of what it takes to have your app appear on SmartEyeglass.

Thanks,

-Robert

Comment: Thank you for quick and detailed answer.I understood it. I'm going to try using smart-glass SDK samples again.I would like to refer to your samples. Best Regards,  Hiroyasu  Takeda

Comment: Robert,  Thank you.